Does closing a jar instantly change the temperature?
Temperature is the derivative of energy with respect to entropy. I say derivative and not partial derivative because the defining property of temperature is that heat flows from hot to cold, and this happens because energy redistributes in order to maximize entropy, so it doesn't matter how energy and entropy would change if some other variable(s) of state were held constant. It matters how they will change along the path through state space that the system will actually take as it gains or loses energy.
So, it stands to reason that the temperature of an open jar would be $\frac{\partial E}{\partial S}$ at fixed $p$, and the temperature of a closed jar would be $\frac{\partial E}{\partial S}$ at fixed $V$. So, if these are not equal, then closing the jar should instantly change the temperature. Is this right?
Bonus question, is there an experimental setup where this effect is noticeable? I'm thinking we could put a thermometer inside the jar, but I'm not sure what fluid would make the effect strongest.
Edit: People have pointed out that I'm using different definitions from the rest of the world. So temperature is defined as $T = \left.\frac{\partial E}{\partial S}\right|_V$. Then what I'm asking is, shouldn't $\frac{dE}{dS}$ be the quantity that determines whether energy flows into or out of a system, and matches our physical intuition for what "temperature" should mean? What does a thermometer measure, $T$ or $\frac{dE}{dS}$?

If neither P nor V changes…

Your insistence that it be a total derivative and not a partial derivative has already given you blatantly unphysical behaviour, and yet you have no intention of abandoning the insane for a proper understanding of the theory?

@naturallyInconsistent you're being rude and non-constructive. I got the definitions wrong, fair enough. But you haven't addressed the physical content of my question, ie my prediction. See my comment on the first answer.

But it is clear, from my comment, and the first answer, that your prediction is simply wrong. What more do you want? In fact, if you wanted a constructive criticism, the first answer literally explained how precisely the two scenarios differ, and yet you have not absorbed the lesson. Don't you get that the problem doesn't lie with us?


So, it stands to reason that the temperature of an open jar would be $\frac{\partial E}{\partial S}$ at fixed $p$

It does not stand thus to reason. The fundamental relation is $dU = T\,dS-P\,dV+\mu\,dN$, so the temperature is $T =\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N}$ whether the jar is open or closed. To alter the volume or amount of matter would be to uncouple the energy from the entropy (via work and mass transfer, respectively) such that temperature is no longer exactly the mediating coupling coefficient.
Put another way, the question contains a misconception where the terms kept constant in the definition of a thermodynamic quantity are confused with physical constraints applied in a certain scenario. They are not necessarily the same. (A related issue is students’ incorrect attempt to use $dU = nc_P\,dT$, with molar constant-pressure heat capacity $c_P$, for the internal energy of an ideal gas at constant pressure. The correct relation is instead always $dU=nc_V\,dT$, with the constant-volume heat capacity. “Constant-volume” is simply part of the name of a material property used in the relation, not a constraint. Interpreted another way, the ideal gas is such a simple model that it lacks a volume dependence, so the results are the same as if we had assumed constant volume.) The thermometer one uses at constant pressure is relying on a surrogate electrical or mechanical mechanism, say, that’s been calibrated under appropriate conditions.
$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{P,N}$ is a different quantity equal to $T-\frac{\alpha PVT}{nc_P}$ (thermal expansion coefficient $\alpha$) whether the jar is open or closed. (For the ideal gas, this is $T\left(1-\frac{R}{c_P}\right)$.) The second term accounts for the fact that at constant pressure, expansion/contraction represents a nonthermal way to alter the entropy that must be corrected for when considering the thermal relationship between $T$, $U$, and $S$.

Okay, so temperature is defined as $T=\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}|_V$. Then I'm asking, shouldn't $\frac{dU}{dS}$ be the quantity that determines whether energy flows into the system, and that matches our physical intuition for what "temperature" should be? In other words, what does a thermometer measure, $T$ or $\frac{dU}{dS}$?

If one excludes changes in generalized displacements (such as volume) and mass, so that $U=U(S)$, one could write $T=\frac{dU}{dS}$, and this would affect whether the system is heated by an adjacent system with higher or lower $T$, and one would aim to develop a thermometer that uses some surrogate mechanism (mercury volume, electrical resistance, emitted radiation) that tracks with $T$.
